# Create sub modules in vue like a dll in a c# project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i need to create a sub modules for my project on vue like an dll in a c# project and import it at runtime.

For example, i have an unique dashboard for my customer, and i need a customization for one of them, so i need to build and import a sub modules with some customization.

Any one can help me?

Comment: may be dll is not a good analogy in this case. But you can do alot with components. just create version of components and use if else condition to change them. you make even more customization by making smaller components.

Comment: It depends how they are supposed to interact with main module. They can be dynamic components or independent apps

Comment: I want to make a build of the single "module", in this way i can run build of a smaller module and upload to customer server.
And other things i don't have a single app.js built but more than 1.
I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, the question isn't specific enough. It's unclear how they are supposed to work together. They still can be separate components built as libraries and imported dynamically, or full apps. It's unknown what's your setup. In Vue CLI multiple apps are called `pages` .